# Delete/overwrite a print() message in R

Tags: r

I need to print the number of iteration of a cicle in R:

```
print(paste("iteration",i,"/",ntot))
```

but I want to delete/overwrite this row at each iteration (each iteration is long...). How can I do it?

Comment: This might be preferable to writing your own: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/txtProgressBar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a [progress bar](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/txtProgressBar.html)

```
ntot <- 100

pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 1, max = ntot, style = 3)
for(i in 1:ntot) {
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a starting point

```
ntot <- 15
for (i in 0:ntot) { 
  cat("iteration",i,"/", ntot, "\r")
  flush.console() 
  Sys.sleep(1) 
}
```